# Unpack and change bundle name of a EAR deployment

Tags: maven, gradle, ear

Migrating from Maven to Gradle I'm struggle to find a way to port following Maven configuration block
of the "maven-ear-plugin" Maven plugin:

```
<webModule>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <bundleFileName>my-artifact-v1.war</bundleFileName>
    <contextRoot>/v1</contextRoot>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
</webModule>
<webModule>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <bundleFileName>my-artifact-v2.war</bundleFileName>
    <contextRoot>/v2</contextRoot>
    <unpack>true</unpack>
</webModule>
```

Here I need to deploy a single artifact twice under different bundle names. Besides that, both deployments should be unpacked (within the EAR file).

How could this Maven configuration block be ported to Gradle 'ear' plugin.

(Kotlin notation would be great)